# Why does my Discord bot only return 1 result, regardless of the number provided?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, giphy-api

I'm making a command for my Discord bot, that gets GIFs or Stickers from this GIPHY API Endpoint: https://developers.giphy.com/docs/api/endpoint#search

I have provided the limit to be equal to the number selected by the user, however, it only returns 1, no matter what number I provide.

**The command:**

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

module.exports = {
    name: 'gifsearch',
    description: 'Returns a gif based on your search term.',
  options: [{
    name: 'type',
    type: 'STRING',
    description: 'Whether to search for a GIF or sticker.',
    choices: [
      {
        name: 'GIF',
        value: 'gif'
      },
      {
        name: 'Sticker',
        value: 'sticker'
      }
    ],
    required: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'search_term',
    type: 'STRING',
    description: 'The search term to use when searching for gifs.',
    required: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'count',
    type: 'INTEGER',
    description: 'The number of results to be returned.',
    required: true,
  }],
    async execute(interaction) {




    let resultCount = interaction.options.getInteger('count')
    let searchType = interaction.options.getString('type')
    let searchTerm = interaction.options.getString('search_term')

    if (resultCount < 1) return interaction.reply('You have to search for at least 1 result.')

    if (searchType === 'gif') {
      const res = fetch(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${searchTerm}&api_key=${process.env.giphyAPIkey}&limit=${resultCount}&rating=g`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        if (json.data.length <= 0) return interaction.reply({ content: `No gifs found!` })
      interaction.reply({content: `${json.data[0].url}`})
      })
    }
    else if (searchType === 'sticker') {
      const res = fetch(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/stickers/search?q=${searchTerm}&api_key=${process.env.giphyAPIkey}&limit=${resultCount}&rating=g`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
      if (json.data.length <= 0) return interaction.reply({ content: `No gifs found!` })
      interaction.reply({content: `${json.data[0].url}`})
      })
    }
  
    },
};
```

As I said above, the user can use the `count` option to specify the number of results to return. However, my bot returns only one result in every case. But each number results in a different GIF or Sticker.

I want it to return the number of results that the user provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are only sending `json.data[0].url`, regardless of the `count` the user provides.

To send all images, you could do something like:

```js
interaction.reply({
  // assumes the limit === number chosen
  content: json.data.map(result => result.url).join("\n")
});
```